# Installing Tridion 2013 SP1 on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: 2013-sp1

Is it possible to install Tridion 2013 SP1 on Windows Server 2016?

Answer (score 7):

Like most of these questions, the answer is: it will probably work but will not be a supported configuration.

2013 SP1 is due to be out of support in November - if you're upgrading windows why not look at upgrading to SDL Web 8.5 at the same time.

You can easily see what is supported and what isn't from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [operating system prerequisites for Content Manager server](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-2B8A33B1-33D6-422B-8281-F3087DC0A745) for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 in the documentation.